# Asp.Net Core 2.1 Angular Template on Deployment machine detects environment as "Development"

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, angular-template

Recently upgraded application to 2.1 framework from 2.0. In the dev box(local) everything works fine. Using the [SPA template](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501)

```
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if(env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
```

When the code published to Staging and Production environments, we got npm exception. Then I have added a logger to verify, what is the environment it is detecting.

```
Log.Information($"EnvironmentName = {env.EnvironmentName}");
Log.Information($"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = {Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}");
```

This is the log result in the staging server !

[image: log entry]

We do have other ASP.Net code web api running in the same server which reads the actual value. that is "Staging".

"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" environment variable setting:
[image: environment setting]

I have no clue why it has to behave like this! How to make the application read the actual value of environment variable? From where it is reading the value as "Development"?

Comment: Can you provide the whole startup-code please?

Comment: By default,`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is `Production`, it seems you change to `Development` somewhere. Check `launchSettings.json` and `web.config`. I suggest you try [Setting environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1#setting-environment-variables) to set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` as `Staging`.

Comment: I found the issue. Thank you Tao Zhou,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During publish, angular template generates a web.config with the below entry:

`<environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
      </environmentVariables>`

This is why it was detecting it as Development! But still not sure why this entry is coming by default in the published output.